# How to translate `recipes::step_dummy()` to `dplyr`/`tidyr` code?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, dummy-variable, r-recipes

I'm trying to figure out how `step_dummy()` from `recipes` package wrangles the data. Although there's a [reference page](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/reference/step_dummy.html) for this function, I'm still unable to wrap my head around how to do it using "regular" `tidyverse` tools I know. Here's some code based on `recipes` and `rsample` packages. I would like to achieve the same data output but just using `dplyr`/`tidyr` tools.

I chose `diamonds` dataset from `ggplot2` for this demonstration.

```r
library(rsample)
library(recipes)

my_diamonds <- diamonds[, c("carat", "cut", "price")]
init_split  <- initial_split(my_diamonds, prop = .1)
d_training  <- training(init_split)

d_training_dummied_using_recipe <-
  recipe(formula = price ~ ., data = d_training) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>% 
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) # equivalent to `juice()`. It means to get the training data (`d_training`) after the steps in the recipe were applied to it.

d_training_dummied_using_recipe
#> # A tibble: 5,394 x 6
#>    carat price  cut_1  cut_2     cut_3  cut_4
#>    <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  0.5   1678 -0.316 -0.267  6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  2  0.7   2608 -0.316 -0.267  6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  3  1.7   9996  0.316 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  4  0.73  1824  0.316 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  5  0.4    988  0.632  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#>  6  1.04  4240  0.316 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  7  0.9   3950  0     -0.535 -4.10e-16  0.717
#>  8  0.4   1116  0     -0.535 -4.10e-16  0.717
#>  9  1.34 10070  0.632  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#> 10  0.6    806  0.316 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#> # ... with 5,384 more rows
```

My question is how, given `d_training`, we could arrive an output identical to `d_training_dummied_using_recipe`, by using `dplyr` or `tidyr` (and potentially `forcats`) functions? I've seen posts such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49276914/mutating-dummy-variables-in-dplyr), but they don't seem to fit the current case.

---

EDIT

---

Clearly, `step_dummy()` operates only on `cut` column, and this is because we specified `all_nominal()`. Indeed, `cut` is the only nominal variable in `d_training`. I thought that `cut_*` columns correspond to the levels of `cut`, but then I ran:

```r
levels(d_training$cut)
#> [1] "Fair"      "Good"      "Very Good" "Premium"   "Ideal"
```

which shows 6 levels, whereas there are only 4 `cut_*` columns. So this is one limitation to understanding what's going on.
In addition, how those values in `cut_*` are generated?

---

EDIT 2

---

I've come across the most relevant vignette [How are categorical predictors handled in recipes?](https://recipes.tidymodels.org/articles/Dummies.html) and it discusses the topic directly.

> A contrast function in R is a method for translating a column with categorical values into one or more numeric columns that take the place of the original. This can also be known as an encoding method or a parameterization function.

> The default approach is to create dummy variables using the “reference cell” parameterization. This means that, if there are C levels of the factor, there will be C - 1 dummy variables created and all but the first factor level are made into new columns

Regarding the number of levels vs. number of `cut_*` columns, the vignette says explicitly:

> Note that the column names do not reference a specific level of the [...] variable. This contrast function has columns that can involve multiple levels; level-specific columns wouldn’t make sense.

But ultimately there's no example how to carry the same operation with regular tools (that are not within `recipes` context). So my original question remains unsolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the [source code for `step_dummy()`](https://github.com/tidymodels/recipes/blob/main/R/dummy.R); I'm not sure that I would call it a black box per se. Notice that during `bake()`, it uses `model.matrix()` from base R.

```r
library(rsample)
library(recipes)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'recipes'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step

data(diamonds, package = "ggplot2")

my_diamonds <- diamonds[, c("carat", "cut", "price")]
init_split  <- initial_split(my_diamonds, prop = .1)
d_training  <- training(init_split)

d_training_dummied_using_recipe <-
  recipe(formula = price ~ ., data = d_training) %>%
  step_dummy(all_nominal()) %>% 
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) 

d_training_dummied_using_recipe
#> # A tibble: 5,394 × 6
#>    carat price     cut_1  cut_2     cut_3  cut_4
#>    <dbl> <int>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  0.31   544 -3.16e- 1 -0.267  6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  2  0.72  3294  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#>  3  0.7   2257 -1.48e-18 -0.535 -3.89e-16  0.717
#>  4  0.5   1446  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#>  5  0.31   772  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#>  6  1.01  3733  3.16e- 1 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  7  0.31   942  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#>  8  0.43   903 -3.16e- 1 -0.267  6.32e- 1 -0.478
#>  9  1.21  4391  3.16e- 1 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#> 10  1.37  5370  3.16e- 1 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#> # … with 5,384 more rows


model.matrix(price ~ .,
             data = d_training) %>%
  as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 5,394 × 6
#>    `(Intercept)` carat     cut.L  cut.Q     cut.C `cut^4`
#>            <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1             1  0.31 -3.16e- 1 -0.267  6.32e- 1  -0.478
#>  2             1  0.72  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1   0.120
#>  3             1  0.7  -1.48e-18 -0.535 -3.89e-16   0.717
#>  4             1  0.5   6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1   0.120
#>  5             1  0.31  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1   0.120
#>  6             1  1.01  3.16e- 1 -0.267 -6.32e- 1  -0.478
#>  7             1  0.31  6.32e- 1  0.535  3.16e- 1   0.120
#>  8             1  0.43 -3.16e- 1 -0.267  6.32e- 1  -0.478
#>  9             1  1.21  3.16e- 1 -0.267 -6.32e- 1  -0.478
#> 10             1  1.37  3.16e- 1 -0.267 -6.32e- 1  -0.478
#> # … with 5,384 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The recipes implementation of creating these indicator variables sets up some protection and convenience around learning from training data and applying to new or testing data, as well as more standard naming, etc. This may be a particularly confusing example because `cut` is an ordered factor.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a half answer, but this should help you see how the `cut_*` columns are mapped out. Try this link for a more detailed look:https://recipes.tidymodels.org/articles/Dummies.html

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(recipes)


diamonds |> 
  select(carat, cut, price) |>
  mutate(original = cut) |>
  (\(d) recipe(formula = price ~ ., data = d))() |>
  step_dummy(cut) |>
  prep()|>
  bake(new_data = NULL, original, starts_with("cut")) |>
  distinct() 
#> # A tibble: 5 x 5
#>   original   cut_1  cut_2     cut_3  cut_4
#>   <ord>      <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Ideal      0.632  0.535  3.16e- 1  0.120
#> 2 Premium    0.316 -0.267 -6.32e- 1 -0.478
#> 3 Good      -0.316 -0.267  6.32e- 1 -0.478
#> 4 Very Good  0     -0.535 -4.10e-16  0.717
#> 5 Fair      -0.632  0.535 -3.16e- 1  0.120
```

EDIT:

Here is a little more details:

```r
contr.poly(levels(diamonds$cut))
#>              .L         .Q            .C         ^4
#> [1,] -0.6324555  0.5345225 -3.162278e-01  0.1195229
#> [2,] -0.3162278 -0.2672612  6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
#> [3,]  0.0000000 -0.5345225 -4.095972e-16  0.7171372
#> [4,]  0.3162278 -0.2672612 -6.324555e-01 -0.4780914
#> [5,]  0.6324555  0.5345225  3.162278e-01  0.1195229
```

The `cut_*` columns represent mapping from `contr.poly` and the levels of cut. notice how the cut columns are the same as the `contr.poly` matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, this still leaves the `step_dummy()` black box function unresolved. The link you referenced to is the same one I discussed under *EDIT 2*.

Comment: Does my edit help? I think you can see how you get from the cut to the cut_* columns from `contr.poly`.